# Summarizing individual data in table using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, excel, table, dissolve, summarizing

I am attempting to summarize a a bunch of individual rows in a table I added into ArcGIS Pro, and I'm wondering if there is any type of tool or work flow I could use to do so?

This is kind of a difficult thing to describe in writing, but I basically have 900 rows and 10 columns. There are 70 counties in total, and I am trying to summarize the data in each individual column for the entire county so there will be only 70 rows instead of 900 (but I want to keep all 10 columns). Each row represents a different amount, so I cannot just dissolve to remove redundant info.

Right now I am manually going through the excel spreadsheet and summarizing the data for each county, but it is taking forever and there has to be another way to do this quickly. This is not public data so I cannot upload it, but I will upload an example with generic amounts.

[image: Excel Table]

Comment: The ArcPro Summary statistic tool will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In Pro you may also run most of the geoprocessing tools in batch:

[image]